# How do I parse a plain HTML table with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xpath, html-parsing, nokogiri

I'd like to parse a HTML page with the Nokogiri. There is a table in part of the page which does not use any specific ID. Is it possible to extract something like:

```
Today,3,455,34
Today,1,1300,3664
Today,10,100000,3444,
Yesterday,3454,5656,3
Yesterday,3545,1000,10
Yesterday,3411,36223,15
```

From this HTML:

```
<div id="__DailyStat__">
  <table>
    <tr class="blh"><th colspan="3">Today</th><th class="r" colspan="3">Yesterday</th></tr>
    <tr class="blh"><th>Qnty</th><th>Size</th><th>Length</th><th class="r">Length</th><th class="r">Size</th><th class="r">Qnty</th></tr>
    <tr class="blr">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>455</td>
      <td>34</td>
      <td class="r">3454</td>
      <td class="r">5656</td>
      <td class="r">3</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="bla">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1300</td>
      <td>3664</td>
      <td class="r">3545</td>
      <td class="r">1000</td>
      <td class="r">10</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="blr">
      <td>10</td>
      <td>100000</td>
      <td>3444</td>
      <td class="r">3411</td>
      <td class="r">36223</td>
      <td class="r">15</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a quick and dirty first pass I'd do:

```
html = <<EOT
<div id="__DailyStat__">
  <table>
    <tr class="blh"><th colspan="3">Today</th><th class="r" colspan="3">Yesterday</th></tr>
    <tr class="blh"><th>Qnty</th><th>Size</th><th>Length</th><th class="r">Length</th><th class="r">Size</th><th class="r">Qnty</th></tr>
    <tr class="blr">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>455</td>
      <td>34</td>
      <td class="r">3454</td>
      <td class="r">5656</td>
      <td class="r">3</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="bla">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1300</td>
      <td>3664</td>
      <td class="r">3545</td>
      <td class="r">1000</td>
      <td class="r">10</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="blr">
      <td>10</td>
      <td>100000</td>
      <td>3444</td>
      <td class="r">3411</td>
      <td class="r">36223</td>
      <td class="r">15</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
EOT

#    Today              Yesterday
#    Qnty Size   Length Length Size  Qnty
#    3    455    34     3454   5656  3
#    1    1300   3664   3545   1000  10
#    10   100000 3444   3411   36223 15


require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
```

Use CSS to find the start of the table, and define some places to hold the data we're capturing:

```
table = doc.at('div#__DailyStat__ table')

today_data     = []
yesterday_data = []
```

Loop over the rows in the table, rejecting the headers:

```
table.search('tr').each do |tr|

  next if (tr['class'] == 'blh')
```

Initialize arrays to capture the pertinent data from each row, selectively push the data into the appropriate array:

```
  today_td_data     = [ 'Today'     ]
  yesterday_td_data = [ 'Yesterday' ]

  tr.search('td').each do |td|
    if (td['class'] == 'r')
      yesterday_td_data << td.text.to_i
    else
      today_td_data << td.text.to_i
    end
  end

  today_data     << today_td_data
  yesterday_data << yesterday_td_data

end
```

And output the data:

```
puts today_data.map{ |a| a.join(',') }
puts yesterday_data.map{ |a| a.join(',') }

> Today,3,455,34
> Today,1,1300,3664
> Today,10,100000,3444
> Yesterday,3454,5656,3
> Yesterday,3545,1000,10
> Yesterday,3411,36223,15
```

Just to help you visualize what's going, at the exit from the "tr" loop, the `today_data` and `yesterday_data` arrays are arrays-of-arrays looking like:

```
[["Today", 3, 455, 34], ["Today", 1, 1300, 3664], ["Today", 10, 100000, 3444]]
```

Alternatively, instead of looping over the "td" tags and sensing the class for the tag, I could have grabbed the contents of the "tr" and then used `scan` to grab the numbers and sliced the resulting array into "today" and "yesterday" arrays:

```
  tr_data = tr.text.scan(/\d+/).map{ |i| i.to_i }

  today_td_data     = [ 'Today',     *tr_data[0, 3] ]
  yesterday_td_data = [ 'Yesterday', *tr_data[3, 3] ]
```

In real-world development, like at work, I'd use that instead of what I first wrote because it's succinct.

And notice that I didn't use XPath. It's very doable in Nokogiri to use XPath and accomplish this, but for simplicity I prefer CSS accessors. XPath would have allowed accessing individual "td" tag contents, but it also would begin to look like line-noise, which is something we want to avoid when writing code, because it impacts maintenance. I could also have used CSS to drill down to the correct "td" tags like `'tr td.r'`, but I don't think it would improve the code, it would just be an alternate way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks @the-tin-man. It worked properly, just I have to change doc.at to doc.css as getting some error. I have just some little problem, which I will try to solve. I do not have enough reputation to vote so cheer up :)

Comment: `at` works with both CSS and XPath, but only returns the first occurrence of the node, so you might have multiple `table` tags. `css` is an alias to `search` which returns a NodeSet, AKA an array of Nodes, so you have to index into the results, or iterate over them. `at_css` is the CSS specific equivalent to `at`.

Comment: @JraNil, Also, as a FYI, the code works with your sample HTML, so there must be something missing in the sample. If you generate an accurate sample we can provide better answers.

Comment: Yes, It seems there are some problem with the original web page. It dose not response when I am calling it with open-uri or wget. I am trying to make an agent and using Mechanize to call the page.